# Declare variable in Scala

Tags: scala

I just new in Scala, I know Scala have three keywords to declare variables is:

```
def defines a method
val defines a fixed value (which cannot be modified)
var defines a variable (which can be modified)
```

I am going to write some code to test with an anonymous method.

```
object Anonymous {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def double_1 = (i: Int) => { i * 2 }
    val double_2 = (i: Int) => { i * 2 }
    var double_3 = (i: Int) => { i * 2 }
    println(double_1(2))
    println(double_2(2))
    println(double_3(2))
  }
}
```

- What is the difference about three ways above, when I use double_1, double_2, double_3?
- What is the memory segment have to store the variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, they are not anonymous methods.  They are functions and they each have a name so they are not anonymous.

The main difference between them is that `double_3` can be reassigned to some different function value.

```
var double_3 = (i: Int) => { i * 2 }
double_3 = (i: Int) => i + 3  // the compiler allows this
```

The others cannot.

It would be rather unusual to defined a function as a `def`.  `def` is mostly used to declare methods because a `def` is re-evaluated every time it is referenced.

```
def x = 3 + 4
val y = 3 + 4
```

Both `x` and `y` evaluate to 7, but the addition is redone every time `x` is referenced.  For `y` the addition is done once, at the definition, and never again.